# Struggling with XCode Settings for ios deeplinking on flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ios-universal-links

My app should open when someone clicks on a link like:
https://catalogscanner.horizonpedia.com/P7GWqM6ADnG
This works on my android phone so I assume that I have done everything correctly on the coding site. (I am using https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links for that)
So I started by adding the domain to my runner.entitlemens as you can see.
The Target Membership category shows that there is runner not ticked:

[image]

When I tick the box and start the build, it fails with the error message below:

[image]

To fix this, I have to remove the info. plist from the "Copy Bundle Resources" from my "Build Phases" Section:

[image]

If my understanding is correct then The target membership of the runner entitlement should be the Runner, shouldn't it?

Can I try other things to troubleshoot?

Comment: Are you using firebase's dynamic link?

Comment: No, I am using flutters uni_link package https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of those files should need to have their **Target Membership** checkbox checked. These checkbox mainly applies to source files such as typical Swift files (.swift) or Objective-C implementation files (.m) for example.

They should not also be part of the **Copy Bundle Resources** phase. You just should ensure that in the Build Settings pane of your app target, the Info.plist file is correctly set like below:

[image: Packaging section of Build Settings]

Regarding the Universal Link support, you first have to be sure that the `apple-app-site-association` file you uploaded is correctly formatted (I just checked via your domain and it seems to be invalid JSON as my browser Firefox told me that it had issues parsing it; you can also look for AASA validator online that will confirm this).

The process is the following: when iOS will install your app, it will look for the domain you mentioned in your .entitlements file. Then it will retrieve the AASA file from this specified domain and register your app as a handler for those link. Then, if you happen to browse or click to/on a link matching the paths you specified in the AASA file, then your app should launch and you'll have appropriate callbacks in your application delegate where you can intercept the link and take appropriate actions.

If you want more information about Universal Link support, you can look on [Apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content).